# How to make a labelSwitch do something when I turn it on and off?

Tags: java, blackberry

When I press my switch so that it shows the "on" position, how do I actually make it do something, for example, link it to a method that sets the volume of a player to 0? I'm guessing its Interface `FieldChangeListener`?

All my implementation occurs in the `MainScreen` class.

```
Bitmap switch_left = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_left.png");
Bitmap switch_right = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_right.png");
Bitmap switch_left_focus = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_left_focus.png");
Bitmap switch_right_focus = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("switch_right_focus.png");

LabeledSwitch silentSwitch = new LabeledSwitch(switch_left, switch_right, switch_left_focus, switch_right_focus, "on", "off", true );
JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager silent = new JustifiedHorizontalFieldManager( new LabelField( "Silent Mode" ), silentSwitch, false, USE_ALL_WIDTH );
silent.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
add(silent);
```

I imported a game demo called OpenGlSpriteDemo, and looked at how they implemetned the start button with field change listener, so I tried to do that for the Labeledswitch. Am I heading in the right direction?

```
LabeledSwitch silentSwitch = new LabeledSwitch(switch_left, switch_right, switch_left_focus, switch_right_focus, "on", "off", false );
silentSwitch.setChangeListener(this);

public void fieldChanged(Field arg0, int arg1) 
{
    //If user sets the switch to on, reduce the volume to 0, 
    // else if user sets the switch to false, change it back 
    // to the default volume    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are heading in the right direction. But before playing with complex and customized `Field` objects, did you try some elementary UI Components, such as `ButtonField`? You need to register a `FieldChangeListener` instance to a Field to get notified when a change event occurs. And your last segment of code isn't correct. Writing a sample application which will use a `ButtonField`, and `FieldChangeListener` may help you to understand how the change listener works.

Comment: Thanks Rupak. My app plays a custom wav file everytime I disconnect and connect a USB cable, and I wanted to implement this switch to turn that on and off. I figured it now by using a boolean variable.

Comment: You should probably just post a separate question on the backlight topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using a boolean flag to tell if its silent already or not, and used a get and set methods of the volume variable and pass it to:

```
volume.setLevel(getVolume());
```

and

```
boolean isSilent = false;

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
    if(!isSilent && field == silentSwitch)
    {
        setVolume(0);
        isSilent = true;
    }
    else if(field == silentSwitch && isSilent)
    {
        setVolume(20);
        isSilent = false;           
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work fine, but also, the `LabeledSwitch` class has a method named `getOnState()` that will actually tell you whether it's on or off.  So, you shouldn't really **need** to keep track of it with your own `isSilent` variable.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that method out. Where can I find all the methods of LabledSwitch? I can't find any docs on this class.

Comment: woops, looks like all the methods and their descriptions are inside the com.samples.toolkit.ui.component java files. :D

Comment: right.  It's not part of the *official* RIM libraries, so I would just consult the source code you have, as part of the **Advanced UI** download.